# Writing php database class that's easy to replace

Tags: php, database, class

I'm developing a small PHP application which requires some database interaction. It's all fine until I come to the point of versatility and integration as I want the application to be easy to implement into other websites.

My concerns are, is it a good practice to have two database classes running side by side as the web site my application would be integrated in might have one of it's own. Here comes the big question how (or even should I?) to make the database class in such a manner that it would be easy to replace it with another one.

My ideas so far are either to

- just use my own class so the user can define his database connection

or

- create the class using some general function naming rules, like `$this->db->Query(); $this->db->fetchAll()` so it is easy to extend and the functions could be replaced by the web sites native ones.

I'm keeping the class small, with very few functions, still I'm pretty stumped on how to create this for it to be as dev-friendly as possible.

Thanks,
M.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is what you are looking for.

Comment: You're not the only one who has faced the problem like this one. You're actually looking for a framework (your own/or 3rd). Zend 2->DB is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the most popular php data object interfaces:

1. [MySQLi - Builtin PHP database interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
2. [PDO - Builtin PHP data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
3. [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)
4. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
5. [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

Answer (score 0):

*"Is it a good practice to have two database classes running side by side?"* No, it does not make sense...?

I would use a specific DB-class that could be easily transfered to another site. I would use the PDO-object to achieve this.  settings.ini should be stored outside the webroot because login credentials etc are store there.

```
<?php
class DB_Instance
{
    private static $db;

    public static function getDBO()
    {
        global $dbSettings;
        global $dsn;
        global $user;
        global $password;

        if (!self::$db)

            //Get connection parameters from ini-file
            $dbSettings = parse_ini_file('settings.ini', true);
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $dbSettings['database']['name'] . ';host=' . $dbSettings['database']['host'];
            $user = $dbSettings['database']['user'];
            $password = $dbSettings['database']['password'];

            try {   
                $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
            self::$db = $dbh;

        return self::$db;
    }
}
?>
```

and then accessed by a class like this:

```
<?php
class Language {
    private $languageId;                //Language identifier
    private $language;                  //Which language
    private $dbInstance;                //DBInstance

    public function __construct($languageId = null) {
        $this->dbInstance = DB_Instance::getDBO();
....
```

and then execute functions like this:

```
$statement = $dbInstance->{PDO function}
```

For more information about PDO Class, look: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php